# How to connect php and MS SQL in LAMP

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc

I am trying to connect php with ms sql server in lamp environment.

```
 $con = new PDO('odbc:Driver=FreeTDS; Server=HOST; Database=TWO; UID=sa; PWD=123456789;');
```

I go through like 100+ suggestion.Nothing works ,

all i get is a BIG and SAME Error **SQLSTATE[IM002] SQLDriverConnect: 0 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified**

Can anyone please give a working example, they might tried already.

Comment: You're forgetting the port in your connection string.

Comment: i did that too 1433.

Comment: your `sa` account is active, and remotely accessible? Enjoy having your db and possibly server destroyed...

Comment: yes its' active only. I tried to connect from window machine with ADODB in PHP and XAAMP.It's Working Fine BUT showing the same error  if connected with ODBC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have freeTDS installed try one of the following connection string it works for me:

```js
$db = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=YouAddress;Database=YourDatabase", "Username", "Password");

$dbh = new PDO ("dblib:host=$hostname:$port;dbname=$dbname","$username","$pw");//if using dblib
```

Comment: thank you my server is running in linux platform.So i use dblib its working fine. Thank you again.